# Passing scope from template to link in a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm attempting to pass a local scope from my template to my link function. For whatever reason the code is not working. I thought since the scope is local to the template it would automatically appear in the scope variable for the link function, but that is not the case. My code below:

```
function clicker() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: false,
    template: "<input ng-model='email'><button id='button'>submit</button>",
    link:function (scope, element, attrs) {
      angular.element('#button').on('click', function(){
        console.log(scope) // should be seeing email in the scope
      })
    }
  };

  return directive;
}
```

Comment: Sorry that's not the issue. That was a mistake on my part.

Comment: is the problem solved? for me your code is working when i include jquery before angular http://jsfiddle.net/Lm7e024s/

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of obvious where you going wrong. You need to either escape your quotes or change to single quotes inside double quotes

Comment: Not the issue. Sorry. That was a mistake on my part. The quotes are formatted correctly, the problem still persists.

Comment: "<input ng-model=\"email\"><button id=\"button\">s

Answer (score 0):

require : 'ngModel'

link:function (scope, element, attrs, model) {

Comment: I'm receiving a compiling issue. `Error: [$compile:ctreq]`